# Macbook Pro Early 2011 17" dGPU problem

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hardware, gpu

I have bought a Macbook Pro Early 2011 17 inch (A1297) with the known AMD GPU problem. I'd like to fix that in the near future using the Demux or Tiresias solution.

Now, before doing that, I tried to bypass the AMD GPU with software, so I did this tutorial:
https://gist.github.com/cdleon/d1eff7246a25193304284ecec40445b0

I've succesfully done the tutorial before on a A1286 late 2011, so I figured it would work on my 17 inch Macbook Pro early 2011 (A1297). The weird colours and stripes dissapeared... except for a vertical white bar. (as seen on the picture)
[image: My Macbook Pro early 2011 17" A1297 i7]

Does anyone know a solution for this? Might this be the intel GPU? Do I need to look somewhere else?
I'm pretty sure it's not the display itself (as it does not have any crack or damage).

Thanks!
Lorenzo